# GCS: Retry on 410 gone errors in BlobWriteChannel.flushBuffer

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We are using GCS to store blob files. We provide a GCS implementation of an interface provided by an internal library. The implementation returns a `WritableByteChannel` which is used by the library. This means, adding a retry logic is not an easy option for us. Looking at the stack trace below, we see that it is created in the `BlobWriteChannel.flushBuffer` method.

Is there any way for me to retry on such errors?

```
Caused by: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: 410 Gone
! {
!  "error": {
!   "errors": [
!    {
!     "domain": "global",
!     "reason": "backendError",
!     "message": "Backend Error"
!    }
!   ],
!   "code": 500,
!   "message": "Backend Error"
!  }
! }
! 
! at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:227)
! at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.write(HttpStorageRpc.java:762)
! at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobWriteChannel$1.run(BlobWriteChannel.java:51)
! at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
! at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
! at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
! at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
! at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobWriteChannel.flushBuffer(BlobWriteChannel.java:44)
! at com.google.cloud.BaseWriteChannel.close(BaseWriteChannel.java:151)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the error 410 gone. And according to the GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#410_Gone), “410 gone” means you are trying to upload a file by reusing an invalid session. However, this error you observed seems a known issue, which was reported on this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/137168102). I recommend that you follow up on the link for updates and fixes.

Comment: Considering my use case where I am responsible for providing an implementation for an interface exposed by a library, it would be difficult to add a retry logic. I am not completely sure if the retries are happening as part of the SDK implementation.

Comment: The error message in your descriptions shows that the class DirectRetryingExecutor was called. This class is part of the Google API extension for [Java](http://googleapis.github.io/gax-java/1.8.1/apidocs/com/google/api/gax/retrying/DirectRetryingExecutor.html). I assumed it was called by the SDK, or did you call this retry class yourself?

Comment: It was called by the SDK but not sure what the default retry count is etc.

Comment: Great! The SDK indeed retried in your setup. After I researched further, actually, the 410 error you observed seems a known issue, which was reported on this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/137168102). You can follow up on the link for updates and fixes.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, we've been seeing 410 GONE errors occasionally during big uploads or compose() calls.  We are working with Google support about this. To quote:

> As of right now, the issue is a bug and not a customer issue, and while a fix is on the way, there is a workaround that can be done on the customer’s side. The official workaround to circumvent 5xx and 410 errors is to implement retries, as was indicated in this comment from a Issue Tracker entry you have commented yourself (see this [blog comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137168102#comment2)). The retry method recommendation can also be seen in [this discussion](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35903805#comment2).
>
> To retry successfully, catching 500 and 410 errors is required and, as the [official documentation recommends](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#410_Gone), implementing a retry by starting a new session for the upload that received an unsuccessful status code but still needs uploading. The new session creation may be what was missing on your end, causing retries to be unsuccessful as you have mentioned previously. Additionally, exponential backoffs recommended in [comments](https://issuetracker.google.com/35903805#comment2) are the way to go to mitigate the issue -- see the [docs about that](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff).